# Insertar datos con each a una tabla jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Actualmente recorro un array y voy mostrando datos en una tabla, de forma dinamica, lo que me sucede es que inserta todos los valores en la ultima fila de la tabla y se salta la primera, de que forma puedo hacer para que los datos los inserte desde la primera fila hasta la ultima ?

```
 $.each(objView.ArrayStock, function(indice, elemento) {
        $.each(elemento, function(indice2, elemento2) {
        $("#table1 td:last").before('<td>'+elemento2.STOCK_REAL+'</td>');
       /* uso el last para insertarlo entre dos columnas */          
        })

     });
```

Esta es mi tabla , necesito insertar los datos dela array entre dos columnas de mi tabla ya construida previamente.

```
    <table id="table1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Codigo</th>
              <th>Precio</th>
              <th>Eliminar</th>                                               
          </tr>
         </thead>

      <tbody>                                             
         <tr >
            <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO               
            </td><td>08852</td>
/*entre estas dos columnas necesito ingresar los datos del array/* 
            <td>45000</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO</td>
          <td>05215</td>
/*entre estas dos columnas necesito ingresar los datos del array*/ 
          <td>44000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>  
    </table>
```

Mi problema es que se insertan todos los datos del array en la ultima columna ejemplo de mi error :

```
<tbody>                                             
             <tr >
                <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO               
                </td><td>08852</td>
                <td>45000</td>/*aca deberian ir datos pero se la salta la primera fila*/
             </tr>

             <tr>
              <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO</td>
              <td>05215</td>
              <td>44000</td>
              <td>dato insertado</td>/* se insertan en el ultimo tr del body y se salta la primera fila de mi tabla */
              <td>dato insertado</td>
              <td>dato insertado</td>
              <td>dato insertado</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
```

Gracias por su atención saludos.

Comment: ese before de ahi es para colocar los dato entre dos columnas, lo que necesito es seleccionar es que los datos se vayan insertando desde la primera fila hasta la ultima a medida que recorro el array, necesito colocar un indice se me imagina para que seleccione desde la primera fila y no arroje todos los resultados al ultimo tr

Answer (score 1):

Es normal el funcionamiento que tiene hasta el momento , ya que busca el ultimo *td* de su tabla y ahí inserta el nuevo elemento. propongo una solución para esto, seleccionar todas las filas *(tr)* mediante  `querySelectorAll`  de la tabla e iterar sobre estas e ir añadiendo la nueva fila dependiendo del elemento del *Array*

**Ejemplo**

```js
var array = ['Hola1', 'Hola2','Hola3'];
var i=0;
$.each(document.querySelectorAll("#mitabla tbody tr"), function(index, val) {
   if(i< array.length)
        $(val).append("<td>"+ array[i++]+"</td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mitabla" border="2" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Codigo</th>
              <th>Precio</th>
              <th>Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO</td>
            <td>08852</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO1</td>
          <td>052153</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>LIQUIDO DE FRENO2</td>
          <td>052152</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```